# How to implement multipart file upload proxy using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, multipartform-data, multer

We have implemented a proxy server for our main backend server which actually serve all requests using express-http-proxy npm package. This works fine for all request except multipart request, as multipart is not working with this. When i upload a small size file, it works fine as in that case body is redirected to main server once read completely.

In case on multipart request it fails and nothing reaches backend server (as it is trying to load complete body before proxying). On exploration found this https://github.com/villadora/express-http-proxy/issues/127 which clearly says it is not supported.

On further exploration found multer nodejs library which helps support save multipart file, but not sure how to use it for proxying multipart file request to backend server.

Please give some direction of how to proceed on implementing "multipart file upload proxy" using nodejs.

Comment: check for the solution bellow. Works with files array. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69947624/how-to-proxy-multiple-file-upload-using-nodejs/69947625#69947625

Answer (score 0):

One of the best solutions for nodeJS is needle https://github.com/tomas/needle#request-options

and they do support File upload using multipart, passing file path